# Cytoscape3 Desktop: remove labels for traget nodes only

Tags: cytoscape

I'd like to remove the labels for target nodes only (*i.e.* keep the labels for the source nodes). `Style>Edit>Remove Mappings from selected Visual Properties` removes the labels for both, target and source nodes.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do that directly :-(  You could create a column and copy over labels if that node is a source node and then point your mapping to that column, but that could be a fairly big hassle.